# Is using a for-loop on submitted POST data in PHP safe?

Tags: php, ajax, security

I'm always a worry-wart about security in my PHP applications, and I just (potentially) thought of a way a hacker could kill my script. Currently my application takes form data and submits it as an array to a PHP script via AJAX, then loops through this array.

```
foreach($_POST['form_data'] as $field => $value){
   //Do something here.
}
```

However, what if a hacker were to forge an AJAX request, and repeatedly submit the 'form_data' array with 100000000000 random elements? The loop would have to iterate through each element, possibly causing a DoS (or at least slow down service), correct?

I'm not entirely educated here, so I may have some incorrect assumptions. Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will not be an issue: PHP limits the maximum number of POST vars using the [`max_input_vars` directive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars), which defaults to 1000 variables.

This limit is actually enforced to prevent a much more serious type of DOS attack than the one you are thinking about (really, iterating a few thousand array elements is like nothing), namely hash table collision based attacks (often referred to as HashDOS). For more info on that issue see my article [Supercolliding a PHP array](http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/28/Supercolliding-a-PHP-array.html).

Comment: That's an excellent read, thanks for the info! Unfortunately our server is operating PHP 5.2, and I don't have the access to upgrade it. Is there any other way I can avoid POST/GET HashDOS attacks?

Comment: @ACobbs As the issue is pretty fundamental I don't think there is any way around either upgrading PHP or patching the existing version to include the fix.

Comment: @ACobbs "Is there any other way I can avoid POST/GET HashDOS attacks?" Yes - install Suhosin.

Comment: @ACobbs anyway you should use a form token to prevent forging requests

Answer (score 6):

> The loop would have to iterate through each element, possibly causing a DoS (or at least slow down service), correct?

That's true (although the web server's POST size limit, and the script's memory limit will probably put a stop to things long before 100000000000 items).

Also as @duskwulf points out, PHP >= 5.3.9 has [the `max_input_vars` variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) which is set to 1000 by default.

You could still do a size check to be safe.

Comment: Exactly - `if(count($_POST['form_data']) > $expected) die("input issues.");`

Comment: In fact, on modern versions of PHP you'd run into `max_input_vars`, which limits you to 1000 input elements by default.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I think I'll go with the count() option for this case. But as stated by NikiC this really won't do much for security, I'll have to get the server admin to upgrade PHP to prevent those HashDOS attacks...

Answer (score 3):

I generally use `array_key_exists()` for this kind of thing.

If you want to maintain your current loop, try this:

```
$allowed = array('name', 'address', 'phone', 'etc');
foreach($_POST['form_data'] as $field => $value)
{
  if(array_key_exists($field, $allowed))
    {
     //do something here
    }
}
```

or look into something like this:

```
$vals = array_intersect($allowed, $_POST)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ofcourse the hacker might sent all those datas, and it will **definitely** be unwise to iterate through them all. Could do many unexpected things.

I will suggest you trim down your application to only those, which is accepted. What you are doing now is taking all the values from the `form_data`.

Instead of this, you should know **what values to expect**. Could be something like `name`, `address`, `phone` and only iterate through such known values.

Thus, The problem that might occur will be reduced but not completely blocked. With additional size check, like Pekka suggested, you will trim down the risk even more.

Answer (score 0):

Only last version (5.3.10) is liable for use and supports `max_input_vars` by default. But there is good extension - [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/), which provides protection against such kind of attack, as from a lot of others for earlier versions of PHP.